# how to detect bluetooth device type?

Tags: bluetooth, hardware

I want to find out what bluetooth hardware is in my Ubuntu 20.04.1 Dell laptop.  It is not reported by inxi, hardinfo, or settings.  Specifically I'm curious if it uses Intel chipset.  How can I get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options:

```sh
hciconfig -a    # Comes with bluez
lsmod | grep bt # If not even rfkill list it maybe you need to modprobe btusb
dmesg | grep tooth
```

### Reference

- [wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingBluetooth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingBluetooth#Information_required_to_include_in_a_bug_report)
- [wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth)

Comment: Thanks for the options.  hciconfig does not list bluetooth but I get some information from lsmod and dmesg.

Comment: You can check for `systemctl status bluetooth`, also you maybe need to load a kernel module like `sudo modprobe btusb`

Comment: Seems like it's "deprecated".

Answer (score 3):

inxi 3.3.00 has bluetooth reports, finally. Still in prerelease at the moment but should be available by end of January 2021 in distro repos that ship current nxi, otherwise, just update inxi to current version.

```
inxi -Eaz
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Broadcom BCM2045B (BDC-2.1) type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 
  bus ID: 1-1.4:3 chip ID: 0a5c:217f class ID: fe01 serial: <filter>
  Report: hci0 state: up running bt-v: 2.0 lmp-v: 3.0 sub-v: 2ec 
  address: <filter>
  Info: acl-mtu: 1021:8 sco-mtu: 64:1 link-policy: rswitch hold sniff park 
  link-mode: slave accept
```

Due to persistent failures to generate a Bluetooth status report, inxi 3.3.04 added several more methods to identify bluetooth status, and is now fairly reliable. Added to already used hciconfig, the fallbacks bt-adapter, rfkill. Added rfkill status as well to all reports. This finally seems to have locked down for most users bluetooth reports, though still some failures in odd corner cases where bluetooth has been disabled etc. Sometimes rfkill can detect when hardware disabling occurred, sometimes it can't, it varies.

Comment: You might have to edit `/etc/inxi.conf` to update inxi. Open with `sudo gedit /etc/inxi.conf` or `sudo nano /etc/inxi.conf` and change the flag from false to true, save and exit. Then run `sudo inxi -U`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lsusb` from a terminal.
For example:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2f68:0042 Hoksi Technology DURGOD Taurus K310
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 12d1:4321 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. UVC Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

On the second line of the output this shows the bluetooth interface.

Comment: user@machine:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e0a2 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:58f4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
- no bluetooth device listed alas

Comment: Not all bluetooth is usb, some of the dual wifi/bluetooth devices for example do not show as usb, there is a pci bus bluetooth type but it's not very common, and also something like raspberry pi have bluetooth on a totally different bus, not usb, not pci, a different type of serial bus.