Cannot connect to Bluetooth for missing default controller in Ubuntu MATE 20.04
i installed gnome in my pc my mistake so got it reformmatted it to get back it normal but now there is no default controller in it so i m unable to connect my bluetooth headphones can i install it myself or i need to call for expert help. and ya my computer have ubuntu not windows
i have tried some solutions on web but no result and i have no experience in ubuntu also so i do not even know basics but tried few codes they did not help i really need to fix this so someone please help i tried instally bluez and other softwares to but it came out that those were already installed
lsusb
ubuntu@ubuntu-Veriton-Z4694G-D22W1:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:009c Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a03:b043 Generic USB Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0461:4e2a Primax Electronics, Ltd USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4650 (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 4692 (rev 0c)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae0 (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 7aa7 (rev 11)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 7af0 (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7acc (rev 11)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7acd (rev 11)
00:15.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7acf (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae8 (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae2 (rev 11)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7afc (rev 11)
00:19.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7afd (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ab8 (rev 11)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7abe (rev 11)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7aa8 (rev 11)
00:1e.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7aab (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a86 (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7ad0 (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 7aa3 (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7aa4 (rev 11)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Device 1dee:5216 (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

inxi -Eaz
Command 'inxi' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install inxi
uname-a

    Linux ubuntu-Veriton-Z4694G-D22W1 6.4.0-060400-generic #202306271339 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jun 27 14:26:34 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux



rfkill list all

    0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no


$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7af0] (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0244]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi


sudo dmesg | grep -i blue

[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
[    3.732300] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.732320] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.732321] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.732324] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.732326] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.732328] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.748856] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
[    3.748859] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    3.748859] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    3.748860] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    3.748861] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    3.748861] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.748862] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader timestamp 2019.40 buildtype 1 build 38
[    3.750604] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file intel/ibt-1040-1050.sfi (-2)
[    3.750830] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-56)
[    3.750833] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[    3.751833] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read MSFT supported features (-56)
[    4.150847] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.150850] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.150854] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized



sudo dmesg | grep iwl

[    3.737041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.738635] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0x501, cnv-id 0x80401 wfpm id 0x80000030
[    3.738658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PCI dev 7af0/0244, rev=0x430, rfid=0x10c000
[    3.739189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-78.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.739213] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-77.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.739234] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-76.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.739258] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-75.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.739275] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-74.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.739383] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-73.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.739402] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.749714] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    3.749751] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.36
[    3.750277] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 71.058653f6.0 so-a0-hr-b0-71.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.875420] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX101, REV=0x430
[    3.983130] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[    3.983173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[    3.983184] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[    3.983195] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x10
[    3.983232] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF HR1 B3, rfid=0x10c000
[    4.024762] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: e4:60:17:9a:8a:80
[    4.043349] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[    4.561841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[    4.561850] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[    4.561858] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[    4.561866] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x10
[    4.607021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0
[19077.769426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[19077.769436] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[19077.769444] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[19077.769453] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x10




ls -lsh /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt*

4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   13 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-0040-0041.ddc
716K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 715K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-0040-0041.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-0040-1020.ddc
716K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 715K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-0040-1020.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-0040-2120.ddc
716K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 715K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-0040-2120.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-0040-4150.ddc
716K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 715K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-0040-4150.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-0041-0041.ddc
616K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 614K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-0041-0041.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-1040-0041.ddc
716K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 715K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-1040-0041.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-1040-1020.ddc
716K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 715K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-1040-1020.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-1040-2120.ddc
716K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 715K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-1040-2120.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-1040-4150.ddc
716K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 715K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-1040-4150.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
576K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 575K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-12-16.ddc
576K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 573K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-17-0-1.ddc
612K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 611K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-17-0-1.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-17-16-1.ddc
652K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 649K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-17-16-1.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-17-1.ddc
612K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 611K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-17-1.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-17-2.ddc
652K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 649K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-17-2.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-18-0-1.ddc
612K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 611K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-18-0-1.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-18-16-1.ddc
652K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 649K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-18-16-1.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-18-1.ddc
612K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 611K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-18-1.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-18-2.ddc
652K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 649K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-18-2.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-0-0.ddc
740K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 740K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-0-0.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-0-1.ddc
740K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 740K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-0-1.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-0-4.ddc
740K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 740K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-0-4.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-16-4.ddc
740K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 740K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-16-4.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-240-1.ddc
740K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 740K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-240-1.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-240-4.ddc
740K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 740K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-240-4.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-32-0.ddc
740K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 740K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-32-0.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-32-1.ddc
740K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 740K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-32-1.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-32-4.ddc
740K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 740K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-19-32-4.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-20-0-3.ddc
740K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 740K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-20-0-3.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-20-1-3.ddc
740K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 740K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-20-1-4.ddc
740K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 740K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-20-1-4.sfi
 24K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  22K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq
 28K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq
 24K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  23K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
 28K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   96 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq
 32K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  31K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq
 40K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
 48K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48K Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-22.50.19.14.f.bseq
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   96 Apr 21  2023 /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq


sudo lshw -class network

 *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 11
       serial: e4:60:17:9a:8a:80
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.4.0-060400-generic firmware=71.058653f6.0 so-a0-hr-b0-71.uc ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:18 memory:6001114000-6001117fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 00:e0:4c:07:fb:6c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.4.0-060400-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:4f804000-4f804fff memory:4f800000-4f803fff


Providing clear details will help, ie. what Ubuntu product & release did you install. You mentioned installing GNOME  (a desktop), so was this a Ubuntu Server install? or something else. Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choice, with the default set by your install media used, but we don't know what you're actually running, thus don't know what options exist for your install.

i just removed gnome refommated it all to default ubuntu 20.04

Please put clarifications in your actual question, but that still doesn't help me sorry; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server has no default GNOME desktop, so you were using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server?? as the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop has a GNOME as its default desktop, so your last comments makes no sense if asking about a desktop system.  (Adding desktop packages to a server system can change some defaults of a server to a desktop system, so being specific with your install & remove packages is required for specific advice; also Server & Desktop installs have different kernel defaults)

ya i was using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server

hi @dr-urmi-arora by definition Ubuntu Server would not have any graphical user interface (GUI). Please edit original post with version info of your Ubuntu installation. This answer from another AskUbuntu thread will help you find it: https://askubuntu.com/a/12497/928088. Thanks.

@dr-urmi-arora Also, please run these commands one by one and post their output to your question: lsusb, lspci, inxi -Eaz. Sources:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1291914/928088 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1311497/928088

Thanks for update; but your question text now mention Ubuntu MATE which is a desktop install; yet in prior comment you said Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, with the Server install having different defaults to a flavor desktop... though flavor desktop install defaults vary on ISO used for install too.

its ubuntu mate i had some confusion i checked it as u said

@dr-urmi-arora It sounds your WiFi/Bluetooth adapter is Intel AX201. Please run these commands and post their output: uname -a; rfkill list all; lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3; sudo dmesg | grep -i blue; sudo dmesg | grep iwl. Thanks.

@dr-urmi-arora Please run these commands and post its output: ls -lsh /usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt*; sudo lshw -class network. Thanks.

In terminal, we can get the firmware from upstream
cd /lib/firmware/intel
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/intel/ibt-1040-1050.ddc
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/intel/ibt-1040-1050.sfi
Reboot
